# Moving up a line in FSI.exe

Tags: f#

Ok, We all love fsi, but I hate it when I type in the wrong thing and then I want to go up a line and it won't let me....

Is there some kind of shortcut I am missing?

For example, here is a mutually recursive discriminated union. Oh crap, I screwed it up. I want to go back, but I can't.

How do I go up one line and fix stuff?[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you've already committed the line, you can either redefine it (you can define the same types/functions as many times as you want in FSI), or start over. That's why the preferred way to use FSI is: write the code in a script file and 'Send to Interactive'. That avoids this issue.